# LNK2019 error- external simbol not found. Tried several solutions

Tags: c++, linker

I've already searched a lot for this issue, but none of the results helped me to fix this. The thing is, I'm using M visual studio, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

When compiling my code, using some .h files to modulate, I get the LNK2019 error. This is the code I have already:

ImageExtractor.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>  
#include <sstream>
#include "../../Headers/FunctionDefinitions.h"
#include "../../Headers/XRIT2PICHandler.h"
#include "../../Headers/DirectoryFunctions.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    XRIT2PICHANDLER X2PHandler1;
    XRIT2PICHANDLER X2PHandler2("Hola");
    XRIT2PICHANDLER X2PHandler3("C:\\tools\\xrit");
    XRIT2PICHANDLER X2PHandler4("C:\\tools");

    cout<<X2PHandler1.DirStatus<<endl;
    cout<<X2PHandler2.DirStatus<<endl;
    cout<<X2PHandler3.DirStatus<<endl;
    cout<<X2PHandler4.DirStatus<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

And the mentioned .h files:

FunctionDefinitions.h

```
int CheckFileDirectory(const char*,const char*);
```

DirectoryFunctions.h

```
    int CheckFileDirectory(const char* FilePath, const char* FileName)
{   
    DIR* pDirectory;
    struct dirent * Entry;
    pDirectory = opendir(FilePath);

    while (pDirectory) {

            errno = 0;

            if ((Entry=readdir(pDirectory)) != NULL) 
            {

                if (strcmp(Entry->d_name, FileName) == 0)
                {
                    closedir(pDirectory);
                    return FOUND;
                }

            } 
            else 
            {
                if (errno == 0) 
                {
                    closedir(pDirectory);
                    return NOT_FOUND;
                }
                closedir(pDirectory);
                return READ_ERROR;
            }
        }

        return OPEN_ERROR;

}
```

XRIT2PICHandler.h

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>


const char* DEFAULTPATH="C:\\Tools\\xrit";
const char* DEFAULTCOMMAND="\\xrit2pic_cmd -nogui";
const char* PROGRAMNAME="xrit2pic_cmd.exe";
const int OPEN_ERROR=-10;
const int NOT_FOUND=-11;
const int READ_ERROR=-12;
const int FOUND=10;


class   XRIT2PICHANDLER
{
    public:
        //Atributos
        std::string XRIT2PICPath;
        std::string Command;
        //DIR * pDirectory;
        //struct dirent *Entry;
        int DirStatus;

        //Constructores
        //Por defecto se usa la instalación en C:\\Tools\\xrit
        XRIT2PICHANDLER();

        //Constructor parametrizado
        XRIT2PICHANDLER(const char*);

        //Destructor
        ~XRIT2PICHANDLER();

        //Métodos


};

//Implementacion de los constructores
//Por defecto
XRIT2PICHANDLER::XRIT2PICHANDLER()
{   
    DirStatus=CheckFileDirectory(DEFAULTPATH,PROGRAMNAME);

    if(DirStatus==FOUND)
    {
        XRIT2PICPath=std::string(DEFAULTPATH);
        XRIT2PICPath=std::string(DEFAULTCOMMAND);

    }
}

//constructor parametrizado
XRIT2PICHANDLER::XRIT2PICHANDLER(const char* Path)
{
    DirStatus=CheckFileDirectory(Path,PROGRAMNAME);

    if(DirStatus==FOUND)
    {
        XRIT2PICPath=std::string(DEFAULTPATH);
        XRIT2PICPath=std::string(DEFAULTCOMMAND);
    }

}
```

Just to mention, I simplified the program but the error keep's appearing. I've done several structures similar to this, so I'm probably missing something but I did searched a lot. Will be very happy if someone point to me the issue, I've been through it a lot.

```
Error code:
Compilación iniciada a las 20/10/2015 13:39:33.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Aplicando tarea Touch a "Debug\ImageExtractor.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  ImageExtractor.cpp
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  Todas las salidas están actualizadas.
1>ImageExtractor.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: __thiscall XRIT2PICHANDLER::~XRIT2PICHANDLER(void)" (??1XRIT2PICHANDLER@@QAE@XZ) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _main
1>C:\Users\sesel\Google Drive\PFC Telecomunicaciones\C++\ImageExtractor\Debug\ImageExtractor.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externos sin resolver
1>
1>ERROR al compilar.
1>
1>Tiempo transcurrido 00:00:00.66
========== Generar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
```

By the way, I made sure .h files are in the correct folders, and sorry for comments in spanish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can tell from the error message it is looking for `~XRIT2PICHANDLER()`, which you haven't provided a body for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to implement a destructor function.
Try to replace `~XRIT2PICHANDLER();` with `~XRIT2PICHANDLER() {};`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I was assuming that destructor was ok and haven't realized it. I used a template to create the classes, so for sure missed it this time.